# How to store phantom type using Scala / Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

Suppose I have

```
sealed trait Status
sealed trait Released extends Status
sealed trait Deleted extends Status
```

and

```
case class Album[S <: Status](artist: String, id: Long)
```

Is there some neat way how to store and map this using Slick 3.1?